# How to open port from hotspot

Tags: networking, xubuntu, hot-spot, ap-hotspot, ros

I have created an hotspot with xubuntu 16.04. I can `ping` the 2nd from the 1st and the 1st from the 2nd, but with `ssh` I can't reach the 1st PC where the hotspot is configured.

This is the error I am receiving:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.42.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

I have the same problem with my C++ program that send ROS message over the port 11311. It works only in one direction. Is there any way to enable the port?